# how do i run a c++ file in a separate terminal from another c++ file?

Tags: c++, terminal, gnome-terminal

I am new to ubuntu and was exploring the terminal. I got stuck here. I have two c++ files x.cpp and y.cpp . I am running x from the first terminal. It has a line as follows:

```
system("gnome-terminal");
```

this opens a new terminal window. Next it goes like:

```
system("g++ y.cpp");
system("./a.out");
```

but this runs y in the same terminal window. I want y to run in the newly opened terminal window. Please help.

Comment: You probably should read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and learn a lot more about `fork` & `execve`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each call to `system()` runs a separate new process, as a child of the calling process. There is no relationship between the processes (except that they have the same parent). Each call to system does not run another command in the same context as the previous call, like running on a shell command-line.

You can start `gnome-terminal` with a command to run (instead of a shell prompt) so you can use `system()` to start a gnome-terminal that runs the commands you want:

```
system("gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c \"g++ y.cpp && ./a.out\"'");
```

This will run the command `gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c "g++ y.cpp && ./a.out"'` (but you need to escape the double-quote characters to put the command inside a C++ string literal).

That tells `gnome-terminal` to run a shell (`sh`) with the command `g++ y.cpp && ./a.out`

Comment: thank you @JonathanWakely. This perfectly solved my problem.